# Change Color of Windowframe/Titlebar in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, ribbon

Is there any easy possibility to change the color of the titlebar / surrounding frame of my own WPF-Application, as it is exemplarily done in MS Office Word, Excel, etc?

[image: Change Color]

Comment: Is there any possible sollution, when I want to stay within the normal windows style? For example mahapps.metro changes the whole style of the Windows, but I want to stick within the normal Win-style and just edit the color of the title bar ...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is.
You can easily use the WindowChrome to perform such task.

here are some examples:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1129952/A-Simple-Way-to-Make-a-WPF-Chromeless-Window
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsdk/2010/08/25/experiments-with-windowchrome/
https://www.eidias.com/blog/2014/1/27/restyle-your-window